# Select object by pattern (part of the name) and rename ".001", ".002" and ".003"

Tags: python

I want to rename 4 objects, one original and 3 duplicates.
The duplicates have ".001", ".002" and ".003" in their name. How do I rename:
".001" to "A"
".002" to "B"
".003" to "C"
and the original to "D" using Python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a case where brute force works just fine.  Assuming your prefix was 'Suzanne', you could use this code:

```py
import bpy

bpy.data.objects['Suzanne.001'].name = 'SuzanneA'
bpy.data.objects['Suzanne.002'].name = 'SuzanneB'
bpy.data.objects['Suzanne.003'].name = 'SuzanneC'
bpy.data.objects['Suzanne'].name = 'SuzanneD'
```

the key being that you select the object by its old name and use the `.name` field to change the name.

If you wanted to, say, use the active_object as the source of the name, rather than have it hard coded you could use

```py
name = bpy.context.active_object.name
parts = name.split(sep = '.')
name = parts[0]
bpy.data.objects[name + '.001'].name = name + '.A'
bpy.data.objects[name + '.002'].name = name + '.B'
bpy.data.objects[name + '.003'].name = name + '.C'
bpy.data.objects[name].name = name + '.D'
```

You could be clever and generalize this in various ways, creating code that recognized 'SOMENAME.00n' and made the conversion of '00n' to the character 'n' represents; but that would be overkill for a one off.

Here's an example of more general code to solve the problem

```py
def change_names(name):
    replace = 'ABCD'
    for object in bpy.data.objects:
        if object.name.startswith(name):
            parts = object.name.split(sep='.')
            if len(parts) == 1:
                object.name = name + replace[-1]
            elif len(parts) == 2:
                index = int(parts[1]) - 1
                object.name = name + replace[index]


change_names('Suzanne')
```

There are other ways to code the above, including the use of a dictionary to make the conversion more flexible and using lookup by name to avoid processing all objects; but as you can see, the code just gets more complex with each improvement.

Comment: The first solution is elegant enough for my needs. Can you also do a If object name =/= .001, .002 or .003, then rename to "SuzanneD"? The way I'll be using the script, I won't know the name, only the suffix, because I'll be batching a bunch of files with it.

Comment: The trick for that would be to notice that all of those numbers start with '.' and use the python construct if not '.' in object.name: object.name = 'SuzanneD'

Comment: So how would this line look in python? Sorry, I am completely new to this. 
if object.name --does not contain-- ".", then object.name = 'SuzanneD'?

Comment: @Hologram I added an example of how to do this when you don't know the name.  Basically you get the name from the active object, so you do have to select an object, but then it just figures out what you need,.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your object name is "OBJ", "OBJ.001", ...
the solution should be:

```
import bpy

def rename_4_obj(name):
    objects = bpy.data.objects
    objects[name].name = name + "D"
    objects[name + ".001"].name = name + "A"
    objects[name + ".002"].name = name + "B"
    objects[name + ".003"].name = name + "C"

rename_4_obj("OBJ")
```

But if you don't know the object name, the solution should be:

```
import bpy

dic = {
    ".001": "A",
    ".002": "B",
    ".003": "C",
}

for oj in bpy.data.objects:
    if oj.name[-4 :] in dic:
        oj.name = oj.name[: -4] + dic[oj.name[-4 :]]
    else:
        oj.name = oj.name + "D"
```

here is the reference of string: https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html

Comment: that will rename every object.  The op wanted only those with a specific name prefix.  You need something like `if obj.name.startswith("Suzanne"):` before your if statment

Comment: Hi, thanks for the post. This site is not a regular forum, answers should be substantial, stand on their own, and thoroughly explain the solution and procedure. One liners and short tips and code only answers rarely make for a good answer. If you can [edit] your post and provide some more details about the workflow and how it works, feel free to restore it, otherwise it may be converted to a comment.

Comment: I ran this code, but it adds the "D" string to the objects with .001, .002 and .003 in their name.

Comment: @X Y
So there is something going wrong with the line: 
else: obj.name = obj.name + "_Winter"